# Qualitative behavior of linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose we have the linear differential equation $$\frac{dy}{dt}+2y=b(t)$$ where $-1<b(t)<2$ for all $t$. The problem is to give a qualitative description of the solutions. The answer provided is that $y(t)$ tends to a solution such that $-1/2\leq y(t)\leq 1$. It appears the argument goes something like reasoning about equilibrium solutions and the Uniqueness Theorem:  $$\frac{dy}{dt}=-2y+b(t)=0\implies y(t)=\frac{b(t)}{2} \implies -1/2 < y(t) < 2/2=1 $$

where the possible equalities comes from solutions being asymptotic to equilibrium solutions.

The problem for me here is that I don't understand this reasoning or agree with it. For example, why are we allowed to set the differential equation equal to zero and invoke equilibrium notions when the ODE is not autonomous? We know $y(t)$ has to be of the form $y(t)=ce^{-2t}+f(b(t))$ or $y(t)=ce^{-2t}+tf(b(t))$, where $f$ is some arbitrary one variable function, by the Linearity Theorem.

Are we essentially considering that $b(t)$ is any constant on $(-1,2)$ so that if $C=b(t_0)$ for any $t_0$ we have $-1<C<2$ and thus $$y(t)=\frac{C}{2}\text{ for $C\in(-1,2)$},$$ implying $y(t)$ is the set of equilibrium solutions between $-1/2$ and $1$ so that by the Uniqueness Theorem $y(t)$ as a general solution must be bounded between (or equal if there are equilibrium solutions) $-1/2$ and $1$?

Comment: No!  There is no reason why you get $f(b(t))$.  Instead, it depends on the entire history up to time $t$, i.e., $f((b(s))_{s\leq t})$.

Comment: @user10354138 okay...that essentially addresses the irrelevant part of my problem though. There is some particular solution is all that matters, and it usually involves $b(t)$ in some way.